# cryptcat how is possible multiply connection

Tags: tcp

I would like to know if it's possible to enable Cryptcat to handle multiple connections in order to connect to many clients. Alternatively, is there any similar tool that can achieve this?

I tried using cryptcat.exe --broker --listen -p 12345, but it doesn't seem to work